# How to read from the _confluent-metrics topic in Java which is created by kafka

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I want to get the value for sink-record-active-count for one of my sink connectors given here https://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/managing/monitoring.html#sink-task-metrics

I have all containers Running in docker desktop using docker compose file
[docker ps](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NPqKp.png) 
[docker Ps](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LNfBE.png)

I have used confluent-metrics reporter for the task.

Also referring to https://docs.confluent.io/5.4.0/kafka/metrics-reporter.html and https://neo4j.com/docs/labs/neo4j-streams/current/examples/#_confluent_with_docker I have
added the env variables to the kafka-container like this

```
 kafka-service:
    image: confluentinc/cp-enterprise-kafka:5.4.0
    container_name: kafka
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper
    links:
      - zookeeper
    ports:
      - 9092:9092
    expose:
      - "29092"
    environment:
      METRIC_REPORTERS: io.confluent.metrics.reporter.ConfluentMetricsReporter
      CONFLUENT_METRICS_REPORTER_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: zookeeper:2181
      CONFLUENT_METRICS_REPORTER_TOPIC_REPLICAS: 1
      CONFLUENT_METRICS_REPORTER_TOPIC_CREATE: 'true'
      CONFLUENT_METRICS_ENABLE: 'true'
      CONFLUENT_METRICS_REPORTER_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS: http://kafka-service:29092
      KAFKA_BROKER_ID: 1
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: zookeeper:2181
      KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP: PLAINTEXT:PLAINTEXT,PLAINTEXT_HOST:PLAINTEXT
      KAFKA_INTER_BROKER_LISTENER_NAME: PLAINTEXT
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://kafka-service:29092,PLAINTEXT_HOST://localhost:9092
      KAFKA_AUTO_CREATE_TOPICS_ENABLE: "true"
      KAFKA_OFFSETS_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      KAFKA_TRANSACTION_STATE_LOG_MIN_ISR: 1
      KAFKA_TRANSACTION_STATE_LOG_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      KAFKA_GROUP_INITIAL_REBALANCE_DELAY_MS: 100
    command:
      - bash
      - -c 
      - |
        echo '127.0.0.1 kafka-service' >> /etc/hosts
        /etc/confluent/docker/run
        sleep infinity
```

And in the kafka logs I am getting the message

INFO Created metrics reporter topic _confluent-metrics (io.confluent.metrics.reporter.ConfluentMetricsReporter)

I am not quiet sure how can I read from this topic in Java. Also will this topic have the required metrics? related to sink connector?

Thirdly on this page https://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/managing/monitoring.html#sink-task-metrics  there is Mbeans given .. Also i am not sure how to use that . If it needs JMX too I had tried putting KAFKA_JMX_HOSTNAME = localhost   and KAFKA_JMX_PORT: 9010     after following this https://rmoff.net/2018/09/17/accessing-kafka-docker-containers-jmx-from-host/    but I am not sure how to proceed ahead.

Answer (score 1):

To my knowledge, `ConfluentMetricsReporter` is proprietary binary format, and cannot be read without the deserialziation libraries that are part of Control Center.

I suggest using Prometheus JMX Exporter + Grafana to have this data be visualized outside of a Kafka Consumer application or Control Center (such a setup is already offered by the Confluent Helm Charts)

---

Sidenote: Please don't edit any `/etc/hosts` files

Comment: Ohh I see, But I am using community edition of Confluent package and there is a link mentioned in my post which shows using JMX Mbeans and Confluent metrics to get Sink task metrics https://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/managing/monitoring.html#sink-task-metrics.

Comment: Your question shows you're using enterprise brokers. Community and enterprise have the same means for Kafka Connect. I'm not sure I understand. Also, the Sink task metrics would be part of the kafka connect image not the broker like in your question

Comment: Yes @OneCricketeer  i put all those configurations in the Kafka-connect container but I am still unaable to proceed ahead. Help appreaciated. I just want some way to get the sink task metrics for one of my ES sink connector when its running.  Thanks in Advance

Comment: I'm not sure what metrics you're looking for, but like I mentioned, you can use Prometheus insead of Elasticsearch to collect JMX metrics. Otherwise, you need to use Jolokia and Beats. The ConfluentMetricsReporter is not for JMX, it is mostly for lag calculation, which even then can be gotten from external tools like Burrow or Remora